# Check column for substring of values from another column

Tags: sql, sas

I have a list of 100 locations (LOCATION_TABLE) that need to be pared down to 10 based on whether the location is in the target data (TARGET_TABLE). The problem is that the locations do not have the same name, but at least one of the words will be the same.

For example, CITY_SEATTLE in Location_Table matches to SEATTLE in TARGET_TABLE. I could just remove CITY from the Location_Table but this would not work when this is scaled as the prefixes differ.

I have attempted to do this using the following code, but run into problem because the "sub query evaluated to more than one row".

```
PROC SQL; 
    CREATE TABLE UNIQUELOCATIONS AS 
           SELECT LOCATIONS_TABLE.CITY 
           FROM LOCATION_TABLE 
           WHERE LOCATIONS_TABLE.CITY LIKE (SELECT TARGET_TABLE.CITY FROM TARGET_TABLE); QUIT;
```

How might I fix this?

Comment: Sample input /' output data would help. What other prefixes are there? Is there ALWAYS an underscore before the city name?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the EXISTS operator to check if a sub-query has any rows.  The criteria of the sub-query establishes the lookup match.  If your case, the LIKE operator would need % pre and post pended to the target city.  SAS has a convenience operator CONTAINS that does the same.  The INDEX function could also be used to test target city as a substring.

```
%let items = LONDON,NEW YORK,CHICAGO,HOUSTON;
%let pres = SUPER,SUB,GREATER,LESSER,EAST,WEST;

data many;
  do row = 1 to 100;
    item = catx('_',scan("&pres",ceil(6*ranuni(123))), scan("&items",ceil(4*ranuni(123)),','));
    output;
  end;
run;

data target;
  item = "NEW YORK"; output;
  item = "LONDON"; output;
run;

proc sql;
   create table items_like_target as
   select * from many
   where exists (select * from target where many.item contains trim(target.item))
   ;
quit;
```

The trick here is that the many.city is on the left hand side of the operator.  For CONTAINS to work properly the target value has to be trimmed due to how SAS deals with trailing spaces.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `EXISTS`:

```
PROC SQL; 
    CREATE TABLE UNIQUELOCATIONS AS 
           SELECT LOCATIONS_TABLE.CITY 
           FROM LOCATION_TABLE lt
           WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                         FROM TARGET_TABLE tt
                         WHERE lt.CITY LIKE tt.CITY
                        );
    QUIT;
```